# Randomly positioning an absolute element in a div using java script

Tags: javascript, css, random, position

Hello I am new to javascript so I apologize if this is silly however, I am creating a generator that displays a .png for each letter of the alphabet. The goal is to overlap and display multiple images inside of a div, with random positions. So far I am able to display images for each letter on top of one another by creating a random z-index, however I can not figure out how to alter the positioning to random for each picture.

I attempted to create a Math.floor random variable called randomThingTwo to alter the top positioning of the images, but this did not work.

Please help!

here is my current code:

```
var x,y,splitted;

function generate() {

    x = document.getElementById("form1");
    y = x.elements["message"].value;
    var text = [y];
    var joined = text.join();
    var res = joined.toLowerCase();
    var regexp = /[A-z]/g;
    splitted = res.match(regexp);

    var words = [];

    judge();
}

var counter = -1;

function judge() {
    if (counter < y.length) {
        counter++;
        art();
    }
}

function art() {
    img = new Image(splitted[counter] + '.png');
    var picture = document.getElementById("pic");
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var randomThing = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    console.log(randomThing);
    // var randomThingTwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);

    img.setAttribute("src", splitted[counter]+".png");
    img.style.zIndex= randomThing;
    img.style.position= "absolute";
    // img.style.position.marginTop = randomThingTwo;

    img.setAttribute("width", "304");
    img.setAttribute("width", "328");

    picture =  document.getElementById("pic").appendChild(img);

    setTimeout(function () {
        judge();
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: you're only randomizing the z-index, you should randomize the x and y coords also

Answer (score 0):

When setting properties that way, you need to include `'px'` afterward, otherwise it doesn't know what units to use with the number you're passing. Try changing the second line to `img.style.marginTop = randomThingTwo + 'px';`

Comment: Thank you! I tried this however nothing has changed.

Comment: Oh, wow, I totally missed that when I copied and pasted it. `marginTop` should directly follow `style.`, you don't need `position` in there. So, that line should be `img.style.marginTop = randomThingTwo + 'px';`